# Meeting recording transcript and summary

Tags: python

I am a Business Analyst. I attend the all-day meetings and am expected to publish accurate notes. Although meeting recordings are available, they are still 8 hrs. Is there any way I can get a transcript? Even better is a summary of the meeting. Python is the tool we are allowed to use. FYI
Thanks

Comment: Transcript is possible yes, the accuracy of that can be quite questionable depending on language, dialekt and audio quality.

Comment: This might be more of a question of procurement than programming. Google meet does transcripts as does a piece of software called Dovetail (there may be third party pieces of software). Summarization has improved over the last couple of years and there are afew services offering (and libraries implementing this) that you could use. You might like to check out hugging face.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a strong GPU machine and want to learn how to use AI tools, you can use Amazon or Google services:

https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/ai-powered-speech-analytics-for-amazon-connect/

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text